# iOS - In app purchase - Get products price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my iOS application, I've 3 products where users can purchase using in-app purchase.
From my iOS application, i just want to get the price of all the 3 items that are on the apple server.
How can I get only the price without user's intervention. (May be i've to handle in view did load or some method)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need any user intervention to get any product info. All you have to do is to send a product request info and implement a callback method that'll handle the response as shown below (the  example has been taken from http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/):

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.runmonster.runmonsterfree.upgradetopro" ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    [productsRequest release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

Just call requestProUpgradeProductData from viewDidLoad.

Comment: I am trying to call **requestProUpgradeProductData** from viewDidLoad, I get Null product id in the method  **requestProUpgradeProductData** and the app crashes. I have multiple product ids and I want the price tier for 5 products dynamically on my label when the app launches and if the user changes the price tier from itunes my label should show that value. Please help if you can. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.runmonster.runmonsterfree.upgradetopro" ];  Here **com.runmonster.runmonsterfree.upgradetopro** it is a single product id but what to do when there are multiple product ids? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks you. To call the method **requestProUpgradeProductData from viewDidLoad** worked for me.

Comment: The retrieval of product cost getting slower in sometime.

Answer (score 6):

You can create an instance of [SKProductsRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/Reference/Reference.html) with a list of known identifiers at any time. I have it done when the app is launching. It is an async call using a delegate so it is easy to do without blocking.

```
myProductsRequest = [SKProductsRequest initWithProductIdentifiers:someSetOfIds];
myProductsRequest.delegate = myDelegageSomewhere;
```

In your [SKProductsRequestDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequestDelegate/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/SKProductsRequestDelegate):

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
  for(SKProduct *product in response.products)
  {
     [self doSomethingWithPrice:product.price]
  }
}
```

The information is tied to the user's iTunes account. That is how it gets the price for different country stores (different currencies).

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString*)getPrice:(SKProduct*)product{
    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;

    _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    return [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this function to your class.

```
func priceOf(product: SKProduct) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    return numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)!
}
```

Then, you can pass it your product!

```
priceLabel.text = "The price of the item is \(priceOf(product: product))"
```

Replace `product` with the name of your SKProduct.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.x, you will use below

```
public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) { 
        for product in response.products {
          let price =  product.price
          let currencySymbol = productpriceLocale.currencySymbol
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For get price of in-app product, you can use my server.
Works only for available apps in the App Store.

Send post request to:

```
http://195.138.193.194:5003/store/
```

With body:

```
{
  "bundleId": "com.example.bundle",
  "products": [
    "com.example.productId1",
    "com.example.productId2",
  ]
}
```

Comment: What are the bandwidth limitations of your server? Are you sure you want to have hundreds or thousands of requests per day (or hour) from people who saw this answer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: One request takes about 10 seconds. Works in one thread. An hour can process about 300 requests.